# Why does WiFiP2P need internet permission?

Tags: java, android, wifi

Directly quoting the android website :

> Wi-Fi peer-to-peer (P2P) allows Android 4.0 (API level 14) or later
>   devices with the appropriate hardware to connect directly to each
>   other via Wi-Fi without an intermediate access point

But according to the android website, for you to use the WiFiP2P class you have to have the following permission to your application's manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

My question is: If [WiFiP2P](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) connects 2 android devices directly then why does it need the internet permission?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because, as described in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET), the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission actually...

> Allows applications to open network sockets.

No matter if the connection is intended to access the web or not, when one device connects to another external entity (like another Android device), it always uses [network sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket).

Comment: Yes, this is even required if programs on the same device want to talk to each other on the loopback interface, as the socket type is still internet (though it is not required for unix domain sockets).